# Is it possible to set a variable = this to make a copy of the same instance?

Tags: java

What I'm trying to to do is the following:

```
class myClass {
    myClass(myClass o) {
        //copies the variables of o into this class
    }

    void foo() {
        myClass temp = new myClass(this);
    }
}
```

Is this viable to making 2 instances with the exact variables inside foo()?

Comment: You can use `clone()` to do it

Comment: Not possible. In case of reference type `=` will always copy the pointer, not the actual data.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is correct no issue.

But `temp` will be available only inside `foo()` as it is a local variable.

You can modify like below

```
myClass foo(){
  myClass temp = new myClass(this);
  return temp;
}
```

Now you can use

```
myClass obj1 = new myClass();
myClass obj2 = obj1.foo();
```

Now `obj1` and `obj2` will be two different instances having same values in the variables.